# How do you add a comma to the existing delimiter of a Scanner in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I like the current delimiter of the default Scanner, but I would like to add a comma in addition. That way a String like "a , b" will return "a" on the 1st call to next(), and then "b" on the 2nd call.

I tried the following and didn't get the expected results:

```
Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
lineScanner.useDelimiter(lineScanner.delimiter().toString()+',');
```

It no longer leaves the tabs out of the Strings returned from calls to next().

How do I go about adding a comma?

I also tried using the regex operator: '|'.

```
lineScanner.useDelimiter(lineScanner.delimiter().toString()+"|,");
```

When I call next() 3 times with the following String I do not get the right results though:

"   jr nz, .clearsound"

1st: "jr"

2nd: "nz"

3rd: ""

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) says:

> The default whitespace delimiter used by a scanner is as recognized by [`Character.isWhitespace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-char-).

The javadoc of [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#jcc) says:

> Categories that behave like the `java.lang.Character` boolean is*methodname* methods (except for the deprecated ones) are available through the same `\p{prop}` syntax where the specified property has the name java*methodname*.

> `\p{javaWhitespace}` Equivalent to `java.lang.Character.isWhitespace()`

Which means that `Scanner` starts out as-if you did:

```java
lineScanner.useDelimiter("\\p{javaWhitespace}+");
```

Since `\p{X}` is a character class, you can merge it with other characters in a `[ ]`, e.g. to also split tokens on commas, use:

```java
lineScanner.useDelimiter("[\\p{javaWhitespace},]+"); // separate on spaces and/or commas
```

*Note:* Having two or more commas together will not return empty tokens, e.g. `"a , , b"` will still return `"a"` on the 1st call to `next()`, and then `"b"` on the 2nd call.

Comment: What if I want to add brackets to the delimter? ```[``` and ```]```

Comment: @JohnGlen Then escape them: `useDelimiter("[\\p{javaWhitespace}\\[\\],]+")`

Comment: Thank you. I was trying one escape instead of 2.